# Handle facebook expiration token

Tags: c#, facebook-c#-sdk

I am having some trouble while integrating facebook API with my desktop application.

Now, I`m trying to use Facebook SDK for .NET: http://facebooksdk.net/

Here is the problem:

When I use my tokens, Facebook returns the following message:

"Error validating access token: Session has expired at unix time 1365165488. The current unix time is 1378218499."

I saw in some posts that I can do something like this to renew my access token:

```
 Dictionary<string, object> fbParams = new Dictionary<string, object> ();

 fbParams["client_id"]         = token.appId;
 fbParams["grant_type"]        = "fb_exchange_token";
 fbParams["client_secret"]     = token.appSecret;
 fbParams["fb_exchange_token"] = token.accessToken;

 JsonObject publishedResponse = fbClient.Get ("/oauth/access_token", fbParams) as JsonObject;
 return publishedResponse["access_token"].ToString ();
```

But it doesn't work; it throws another exception with the same message ("Session has expired...")

Is there an easy way to do this?

I don't know if this can impact my application but this access token is like 1 year old (and I'm using in a desktop application).

Thank you very much! =)

Answer (score 0):

The message is clear, you are using a token that has already expired (It's actually over four months old). You need to go back through the login flow with a user arriving at an authorization screen.

You cannot extend a token that has already expired, you can only extend tokens that are valid. e.g. a short lived (two hours) token to a long lived token (two months)